# How to store CarName once and prevent duplicates storage?

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, create-table

I have a table called `Person` with the following attributes:

[image]

I want to implement a table called `Car` that will hold information regarding the cars a `Person` drives. I want to implement it in a way that if multiple users drive “Toyota Corolla”, then “Toyota Corolla” should only be stored once as a string. Also it’s only fair that I assume that not everyone owns only one car.  The entries will be recorded on a regular basis but the distinct `Car` records may only reach 5000 only. So far, I have done the following but **how can I implement a property** that will let me save `ModelNames` once if multiple user own the same car.

[image: Car]

```
CREATE  TABLE `Car` (
`idCar` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`ModelName` varchar(80),
`idPerson` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idCar`) ,
FOREIGN KEY (`idPerson`)    REFERENCES `Person` (`idPerson`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

UPDATE Car, Person
Set Car.idPerson = Person.idPerson
WHERE Car.idPerson = Person.idPerson;

INSERT INTO Car VALUES (1, 'Toyota Corolla', 1);
INSERT INTO Car VALUES (2, 'Mazda 6', 1);
INSERT INTO Car VALUES (3, 'Toyota Corolla', 2);
INSERT INTO Car VALUES (4, 'Pulsar GTI', 3);


SELECT DISTINCT Car.idCar ,Car.ModelName,  Person.FullName,  Person.idPerson
FROM Person, Car
WHERE Car.idPerson = Person.idPerson
Order by Car.idCar;
```

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com rather than SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at a many to many relation ship design.

Let say

```
Person
- PersonID -> Primary Key
- Surname
- FirstName
- Title
- etc

Car
- CarID -> Primary Key
- CarType
- CarMake
- YearModel
- etc

PersonCars
- PersonID -> Foreign Key to Person.PersonID
- CarID = > Foreign Key to Car.CarID
```

This will allow you to define the car definition once, and link it multiple times.

You would then be able to select as follows

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Person p INNER JOIN
        PersonCars pc   ON  p.PersonID = pc.PersonID INNER JOIN
        Car c   ON  pc.CarID = c.CarID
```

Comment: Thanks for that, so when adding records, am I adding it to the PersonCars table or the Car table?

Comment: You would add the Person definition to the Person table, the Car definition in the Car table, and then the link between the 2 in the PersonCars table.

Comment: Sorry, I meant as in `INSERT INTO Car VALUES (1, 'Toyota Corolla', 1);` which table would I be inserting this into

Comment: and will this many to many relationship store the duplicate strings only once?

Comment: You would have INSERT INTO Car VALUES (1, ''Toyota Corolla'), (2, 'Mazda 6') and then INSERT INTO PersonCars VALUES(1,1), (1,2)

Comment: Yes, it would store the car definition only once, and reference it multiple times.

Comment: hi sorry to bother you again, is there a way that I would only need to add an INSERT statement to one table and the rest would get updated using the table with inserted records?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, you would have to do the JOINING inserts aswell.